# SQL - Get column value based on another column's average between select rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table something like..

```
[DateValueField][Hour][Value]
 2014-09-01      1     200
 ...
 2014-09-01      24    400
 2014-09-02      1     220
 ...
 2014-09-02      24    200
 ...
```

I need the same value for each DateValueField based on the average Value for Hour between 6-12 for example but have that display for all hours, not just 6-12. For instance...

```
[DateValueField][Hour][Value]
 2014-09-01      1     300
 ...
 2014-09-01      24    300
 2014-09-02      1     190
 ...
 2014-09-02      24    190
 ...
```

Query I'm trying is...

```
select DateValueField, Hour,
(select avg(Value) as Value from MyTable where Hour
between 6 and 12) as Value from MyTable
where DateValueField between '2014' and '2015'
group by DateValueField, Hour
order by DateValueField, Hour
```

But it gives me the Value as an average of ALL Values but I need it averaged out for that particular day between the hours I specify.

I'd appreciate some help/advice. Thanks!

Comment: So `190` is the average `value` between hours `6` and `12` on 9/2, and you want it to be repeated for every record on that day?

Comment: `select DateValueField, Hour,
(select avg(Value) as Value from MyTable b where Hour
between 6 and 12 and b.DateValueField = a.DateValueField) as Value from MyTable a where DateValueField between '2014' and '2015'
group by DateValueField, Hour
order by DateValueField, Hour`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table to get the average value between hours 6 and 12 grouped by date and then join that to your original table

```
select t1.DateValueField, t1.Hour, t2.avg_value
from MyTable t1
join (
    select DateValueField, avg(Value) avg_value
    from MyTable
    where hour between 6 and 12
    group by DateValueField
) t2 on t2.DateValueField = t1.DateValueField
order by t1.DateValueField, t1.Hour
```

Note: You may want to use a left join if some of your dates don't have values between hours 6 and 12 but you still want to retrieve all rows from MyTable.

Comment: Simple and elegant, works great. Thank you. Will accept the answer as soon as I'm able.